# TinyMCE or HTML5's contentEditable attribute?

Tags: html, wysiwyg

I have always hated wysiwyg editors but most of the applications I develop they are necessary for our clients to edit their content.  After trying out a few different ones I seemed to like tinyMCE the best.  Although powerful and seems to generate fairly good HTML it is not without its issues.  Recently I have been thinking about creating a custom wysiwyg that suits my needs perfectly taking advantage of the contentEditable attribute.  Is this HTML5 feature ready?  Will I have many cross browser issues?  What are its limitations?  I guess my question finally boils down to;  Will it be worth throwing in the towel on 3rd party wysiwygs and moving to contentEditable regions?

Comment: Why not to try wysiwyM editor instead of wysiwyG? www.wymeditor.org Let know, if it suits Your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third party wysiwyg editors will also use the contenteditable attribute. The biggest problems is that they really do create tag soup and the same text created in different user agents will have different HTML source.

Personally I would say that you should stick with tinyMCE of CKEdit.

Comment: I noticed that with Cute Editor.  if safari or chrome was used I had spans all over the place with "appleStyle" class.  I guess I will probably face the same challenges.

Answer (score 2):

I say it depends on your scope. If you need something elaborate, massive, and the amount of loaded javascript does not bother you, the use some WYSIWYG. They give lots of possibilities, but also some problems (like this security issue: http://www.devilscafe.in/2011/10/tinymce-ajaxfilemanager-remote-file.html).

But if you need something simple, use html5 contenteditable combined wit execCommand, like this: http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/contenteditable.cfm.

Comment: If you read that security issue you will realize that it's talking about the file manager, not about the HTML editor part.

Comment: That was not my point. What I wanted to point out, is the choice between a possibly faulty open-source software and something very simple that one creates for himself. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: And you're so confident about your coding capabilities that you're sure to fix and avoid problems where other people have been spending a lot of time. There are lots of wysiwyg editors. very simple ones and fully developed ones. Pick one instead of trying to create your own unless you're a coding genius. If it doesn't have all the features that you need, then create patches for it, but you won't be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I have used editors like ckeditor, and no doubt about it, they are great when you need something that can be implemented/used very fast. But that is not enough for me. Client-side speed, beauty, security are much more important. If this means that I have to reinvent the wheel, then be it. I would get a little application which is totally customized for my needs and nobody else's.